# Как получить z-index с сайта?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

Всем привет! Есть такая строчка на сайте: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить и записать z-index по data-id в переменную, а то там много таких строчек?

Comment: все очень просто: берете и получаете)

Comment: @ThisMan логично.. :) ненавижу такие вопросы .

Comment: буду благодарен, если напишите как взять и получить))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с jQuery:

```
$('*[data-id="12"]').css('z-index');
```

Без:

```
document.querySelector('[data-id="12"]').style.zIndex
```

Comment: Большое спасибо))